# If/Else, Try/Catch For Each Or Try/Catch Over Entire If?

Tags: exception, try-catch

Here's some example of some code...

```
Private Sub btnDoSomething_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDoSomething.Click
        If True Then
            Try

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try                
        Else
            Try

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try  
        End If
End Sub
```

Are there any differences to adding a Try/Catch on true and false or just to wrap entire If within one Try/Catch?

Comment: How much "resolution" do you need to respond to the exception correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it all depends on how how want to handle the code featured in each scope. Remember, you can have completely different code in each section, and sometimes you may want to handle the same exception type differently based on whether a condition was met or not.

If you just want generic exception handling (error logging, etc.), then you should place everything inside the try catch.

Answer (score 1):

There surely are differences when speaking generally, but the question is are there differences in your case.

You should only catch an exception when you're going to do something about it. In case your if/else require different actions in the event an exception is thrown then you should put the try/catch inside. Otherwise - outside. And in both cases - only if you're going to do anything about them.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. if the exception handling needs to be different in the If section than it would in the Else section then put the try catch inside each of them. Otherwise surround it.

The same goes for loops. Does an exception mean you need to stop the loop? Then you can surround it. If an exception occurs inside the loop do you need to keep going? Then put the try catch inside the loop. Even if you Dont need to keep going you can do that inside the loop.

This question is too general. It depends on what you want to do.